# How to find the x value of when the slope of the standard Archimedes spiral is infinite?

Tags: calculus

I tried solving this by finding dy/dx and letting the denominator be zero, yielding an equation whose solution can only be approximated. But that approximated value is not right as seen on Desmos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Hosam Hajjir wrote, the slope is infinite when
$$\cos (\theta) - \theta \sin (\theta)=0$$ and the solutions are closer and closer to $n\pi$.

Expanding as series around $x=n \pi$,we have
$$\cos (\theta) - \theta \sin (\theta)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^n \frac{(k+1) \cos \left(\frac{\pi  k}{2}\right)-\pi  n \sin \left(\frac{\pi 
   k}{2}\right)}{\Gamma (k+1)}(x-n\pi)^k$$ Now, using series reversion, for $n > 0$
$$\theta_n=t+\frac{1}{t}-\frac{4}{3 t^3}+\frac{53}{15 t^5}-\frac{1226}{105
   t^7}+O\left(\frac{1}{t^9}\right) \quad \text{with} \quad t=n \pi$$

Trying
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
n & \text{estimate} & \text{solution} \\
 1 & 3.424580679 &  3.425618459 \\
 2 & 6.437295608 &  6.437298179 \\
 3 & 9.529334335 &  9.529334405 \\
 4 & 12.64528722 &  12.64528722 
\end{array}
\right)$$

Answer (score 1):

$r = k \theta $

$ x = k \theta \cos \theta $ and $ y = k \theta \sin \theta $

Slope is $\dfrac{ \sin \theta + \theta \cos \theta }{ \cos \theta - \theta \sin \theta} $

It is infinite when $\cos \theta = \theta \sin \theta $ i.e. $ \cot \theta = \theta$

The solutions can found by the well-known Newton's method.  As a guide towards finding the initial guess of $\theta$ plot $\cot \theta $ and $\theta $ and see where they approximately intersect.  Then the itertions is

$\theta_{k+1} = \theta_k + \dfrac{ \cot \theta_k - \theta_k }{ \csc^2 \theta_k + 1 }$

Once the iterations converge to a root $\theta^* = u$ then

$x = k u \cos u $

Comment: Thank you for your explanation!

Comment: Since there are an infinite number of points at which the slope is infinite, how could I write a general expression for all points at which the slope is infinite?

Comment: It doesn't seem that there is a general expression.